# I want to have a context menu applied to all Activities including listActivities and tabActivities

Tags: android, inheritance, android-activity, contextmenu

What is the easiest way of doing it? I started by creating a class ('OptionMenuClass') that other classes can extend but since I do not want to lose list/tabActivities properties and since Java does not support multiple inheritance I would like to know the easiest way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a base activity which all your activities will inherit. You can then implement your options logic in the Base Class.

Comment: OptionMenuClass is my base Activity. However, I cannot force all activities to inherit this one as some of them already inherit other Activities such as ListActivities and TabActivities.

Comment: I would put custom code in those activities for the menu , still a lot less work and dup code :-)